# Bootstrap 4 tooltip the paradox of closure on self

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

I have to use more than one `tooltip` inside a small div element.

**Moreover**, since this div is "`overflow: auto`", `Popper.js` automatically forces the tooltip to keep inside that element.

When this is the case, the tooltip opens on the element and since there is a cursor there, it falls into a vicious circle, opening and closing tens of times a second.

After the tooltip is opened, I want it to stay open even if we move the cursor on it.

Is there a settings or hack for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to the tooltip `pointer-events: none;` css rule, like

```
.tooltip {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

This will prevent tooltip from being target for mouse events and will resolve the issue.